# Adding "posting" facility to a website

Tags: web

Hi
I am creating a website using HTML and CSS only and I want to add the following feature:
Any person visiting the site should be able to post a message and that message should appear below with his name and time of posting.
How do I go about creating it?
Please help.
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this using HTML and CSS only (at least not in any sane way).

You will need a database of some sort (e.g. MySql, Microsoft Access etc) and you will need some sort of server-side scripting language such as PHP, .NET, Ruby etc.

I suggest picking a language and then finding some tutorials. Most tutorials will take you through using a database.

Comment: Ok suppose I use PHP, then how do i do it? Can u please suggest a tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

This is completely impossible using HTML and CSS only. You will have to use a server-side scripting language.